# Error: You must pass a selector to useSelector with Nextjs and Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

Good evening, I am using REDUX in Nextjs and React to control the states, I already had an application with functional login and registration, but without using REDUX, when I migrate REDUX I receive the following error `Error: You must pass a selector to useSelector` I leave the code below eith userSlide.js for selectors

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Nav from '../components/Nav'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { login, logout, selectUser } from '../config/userSlice';
import Modal from '../components/modal';
import { auth, onAuthStateChanged } from '../config/firebase';

function Home() {
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (userAuth) => {
      if (userAuth) {
        // user is logged in, send the user's details to redux, store the current user in the state
        dispatch(
          login({
            email: userAuth.email,
            uid: userAuth.uid,
            displayName: userAuth.displayName,
            photoUrl: userAuth.photoURL,
          })
        );
      } else {
        dispatch(logout());
      }
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <Nav />

      // Vemos si el usuario esta logueado
      {!user ? (
        // Formulario de Login
        <Modal />
      ) : (
        // display the rest of the app
        <div className='app__body'>
          {/* Rest of the app */}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

userSlice.js

```
export default Home
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    user: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
    },
  },
});
    export const { login, logout } = userSlice.actions;
    // selectors
export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.user;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: can you show what `selectUser` is?

Comment: I think instead of `state.user.user` should be `state.user`. your slice name is "user"

Answer (score 1):

Try like this;

```
const user = useSelector(state => state.selectUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It arose because of the Next cache. The solution was simple: it was necessary to delete the .next folder and restart the project so that the next would regenerate the cache files